# ¿Estoy configurando algo mal? - Locationlistener genera ubicaciones erroneas

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocalización

Buen día, estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde obtengo la ubicación del usuario mediante la clase LocationListener de Android Java, el problema es que algunas veces me ubica correctamente, otras veces me ubica a mas o menos 10 o 20 metros de error(creo que esto es normal), pero el verdadero problema es que aveces me ubica a mas de 2 o 3 kilómetros de distancia de mi posición real, estoy pensando que tal vez tenga algo mal configurado este es mi código:

```
   /*Metodo de ubicacion de usuarios, listener de cambio de posicion*/
    public void LocListener()
    {
 buscando=true;
        /*Se ejecuta cada vez que hay un cambio en la posicion del usuario*/
        final LocationListener milListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                location.getLatitude();
                location.getLongitude();
                rotacion=location.getBearing();
                posicionUsuario = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                    hayUbicacion++;//incrementa en 1 cada vez que se llama a el cambio de posicion
            }

            /*Se ejecuta cada vez que hay un cambio en la configuracion del gps*/
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                switch (status) {
                    case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                        Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                        break;
                    case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                        Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                        break;
                    case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es activado
               // mensaje1.setText("GPS Activado");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        /*Verificamos que se tengan los permisos antes de comenzar la busqueda de la ubicacion OBLIGATORIO*/
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, (LocationListener) milListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, (LocationListener) milListener);
        /*En 5 segundos se verifica si ya se a leido la posicion del usuario 2 veces
        * esto puede ser opcional segun se vea la necesidad de acelerar el proceso
        * de busqueda*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /*Si hay coordenadas entonces apagamos el buscador para evitar bug por tareas largas*/
                if(hayUbicacion>=1) {
                    segundaUbicacion=0;//reiniciamos el contador de busquedas para volver a buscar desde el boton de gps
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(milListener);
                    locationManager = null;
                    //Toast.makeText(MainUsuarios.this, "detiene busqueda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    buscando=false;
                    progressUbicacion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnPedirTaxi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    animacionCamara();
                    mtdRastreadorConductoresCercanos();
                }
                /*Si no han leido las coordenadas las dos veces entonces reiniciamos la busqueda*/
                else
                {
                    LocListener();
                   // Toast.makeText(MainUsuarios.this, "reinicia"+segundaUbicacion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        },3000);//Valor en milisegundos para el reinicio de la busqueda

    }
```

Si conocen alguna solución o saben de algún código que funcione correctamente les agradecería lo compartieran

Comment: ¿En qué condiciones estás probando? El GPS puede dar problemas, especialmente dentro de edificios (o cerca de edificios altos, montañas), la localización por red es aún peor. Mi experiencia (de acuerdo, no mucha) con GIS es que si te equivocas programando no te equivocas por unas decenas de metros, sino que acabas en la otra punta del globo; eso unido a que los fallos vayan variando me hacen pensar más en un problema de recepción/terminal que de programación. Igual esto te interesa: https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2017/04/20/articulo/1492696834_631524.html

Comment: Pues si es cierto que la mayoría de veces que falla es desde mi casa queda cerca a edificios altos pero también me a fallado en otros lugares, pero cuando utilizo otras aplicaciones que también usan Google Maps me ubican correctamente así que llegue a la conclusión de que algo estoy haciendo mal o hay mejores maneras para localizar a los usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo el problema que describes, primeramente debes saber el funcionamiento de los proveedores:

> GPS_PROVIDER : proveedor de ubicación GPS. Este proveedor determina la
>   ubicación usando satélites. Dependiendo de las condiciones, este
>   proveedor puede tomar un tiempo para devolver una corrección de
>   ubicación.
>
> NETWORK_PROVIDER : proveedor de ubicación de red. Este proveedor
>   determina la ubicación en función de la disponibilidad de torre de
>   telefonía móvil y puntos de acceso WiFi.

Si deseas una posición exacta **ambos tienen un rango de error**, regularmente se pide cual es el que esta disponible, pero el más exacto es el del GPS.

Para que sean más exactas tus medidas revisa el método :[requestLocationUpdates()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))

En tu código estas definiendo:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, (LocationListener) milListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, (LocationListener) milListener);
```

- El segundo parámetro es el mínimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos.
- El tercer parámetro es el mínimo tiempo para updates en metros.

Estos son los valores que puedes modificar para obtener menor rango de error, por ejemplo en el caso del `NETWORK_PROVIDER`,

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, (LocationListener) milListener);
```

**tienes definido que cada 5 segundos (5000 ms) o cada 10 metros obtener la actualización de la geolocalización, en el caso de solo tener WiFi en tu dispositivo solo usara este proveedor, la opción es actualizar en menos tiempo y en una distancia menor.**

Como todo tiene un pro y contra, debes tomar en cuenta que si realizas más peticiones en un rango menor de tiempo la batería puede agotarse más rápidamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta tan bien explicada, el problema siempre ha estado en el tiempo que se demora GPS_PROVIDER en devolver una corrección de la ubicación, en mi código tomaba rápidamente las primeras coordenadas que obtenía el listener y  colocaba el marcador en ese punto y esto hacia que tomara la posición con un error de mas de 1km, unos segundos después ya se normalizaba, la solución como dices es actualizar mas rápido y a menos distancia y esperar mas o menos a la 3 o 4 actualización de listener para colocar el marcador